# Handing errors in custom event with jquery trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I control the error handling when triggering an event with JQuery?

We've found that if an error is thrown in a handler function it prevents other handlers from being invoked.

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VPudu/).

The problem is copied below:

```
$(document).on('customEvent', function()
{
  thisIsUndefined.yetIDereferencedIt;
});

$(document).on('customEvent', function()
{
  // Something useful happens here.
  alert('something');
});

$(document).trigger('customEvent');
```

In the above example, I want the alert to be shown. As I cannot guarantee that I have full control over all of the event handlers I'd like a way to hook into trigger and handle errors per event listener.

Of course, alternative design options are welcome.

Comment: can pass data arguments in an event trigger and read it in handler if that helps

Comment: @charlietfl Nope, that doesn't help. The problem is that without control over the function that is passed into `on()`, I can't guarantee that an error won't prevent all event handlers firing.

Comment: really no different than any other error that blocks remaining script from running...  doubt you will find a fix other than fixing error being thrown

Comment: Well, I'm thinking of adding a *shim* function to wrap each function passed to $(document).on, but my attempt at http://jsfiddle.net/hNdUw/1/ doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If event is already defined by some library, and you cannot control that event at all, I would re-trigger that event after unbind that event like the following.

http://jsbin.com/uvivat/2/edit

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
  Undefined.badFunc
});

var prevClickEvent = $._data($("a")[0], "events")["click"][0]["handler"];

//console.log(prevClickEvent);

$("a").unbind("click").on("click", function() {
    try {
       prevClickEvent.apply(this);
    } catch(e) {
       console.log(e);
    }
    alert("hi");
    return false;
})
```

----- edit ----

To go through all functions registered,

```
var prevClickEvents = $.extend({},$._data( $("a")[0], "events")["click"]);

$("a").unbind("click").on("click", function() {
  var keys = Object.keys(prevClickEvents);
  for (var i=0; i< keys.length; i++) {
    try {
      prevClickEvents[keys[i]]["handler"].call(this);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain properly. I have no control over the code that has the error so I can't add the try/catch to that function.

Comment: Perhaps this modified jsbin will help. http://jsbin.com/uvivat/4/edit - compare the behaviour to http://jsbin.com/uvivat/5/edit. As you can see, the problem I'm trying to avoid is the ordering affecting the behaviour here.

Comment: if that's the case, I would go through all event handlers registerd. http://jsbin.com/uvivat/8/edit, tested with Chrome. We could make this possible with pure javascript too.

Comment: While I don't like the use of internal JQuery `_data` this definitely achieves the purpose. I'll mark this as the answer, although we are going to use our own eventing system to solve the problem.

Comment: I don't like it either. I like pure javascript.